# Directory path for executable

Tags: c#, winforms, directory, exe, executable

Hello I’m trying create directory file with text document inside  my first windows form application executable, but something is wrong here:

I want make it available with exe file for other local user computers:

```
string dir = @"C:\Users\Public\AppData\Roaming\AppFolder\document.txt"; 
if (!Directory.Exists(dir))
{
   Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.GetDirectoryName(dir));
   var stream = File.CreateText(dir);
}
```

but  I got this:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.IOException' occurred in
>   mscorlib.dll
>
> Additional information: The process cannot access the file
>   'C:\Users\Public\AppData\Roaming\AppFolder\doc.txt'
>   because it is being used by another process.

Comment: The error is self explanatory. You create the text file but probably never close it

Comment: To get special folders you can use [`Environment.GetFolderPath`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.getfolderpath(v=vs.110).aspx) method and pass suitable [`Environment.SpecialFolder`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder(v=vs.110).aspx) enumeration. Also to write to a text file you can simply use [`File.WriteAllText`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143375(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you need to issue the commands for the stream to be accessible anywhere else

```
stream.Flush();
stream.Close();
```

Comment: Better to wrap it in a `using` block instead - cleaner code :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to embrace to embrace the `CreateText` with a `using` statement. So that is closed after using it. `File.CreateText` will create the file, but it remains open until it will be closed. Attempting to open it twice will result in an `IOException`.

This snippet is part of the example at https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.io.file.createtext(v=vs.110).aspx

```
    string path = @"c:\temp\MyTest.txt";
    if (!File.Exists(path)) 
    {
        // Create a file to write to.
        using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(path)) 
        {
            sw.WriteLine("Hello");
            sw.WriteLine("And");
            sw.WriteLine("Welcome");
        }   
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For accessing / creating file/ directory in AppData  Roaming folder you have to do the following

```
 // The folder for the roaming current user 
string folder = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);

// Combine the base folder with your specific folder....
string specificFolder = Path.Combine(folder, "YourSpecificFolder");

// Check if folder exists and if not, create it
if(!Directory.Exists(specificFolder)) 
    Directory.CreateDirectory(specificFolder);
```